# Can a C++ method have different return types depending on parameters passed to the constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a template class in C++ that has a method that in theory should return a T (specific type) if a certain parameter is 1 (this parameter is not known until an object is constructed), and if the parameter is greater than 1 another instantiation of the class should be returned. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: `this parameter is not known until an object is constructed` - is this parameter known at compile time? `another instantiation of the class` - so it's the same type T or different? Why not just return `std::variant`? Can you provide some code that would _show_ what you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider: You're assigning the return value of that function to some `auto` variable. The compiler needs to be able to decide what type *that variable* has to be... *at compile time*.

So no, there is no way to do it. You can use e.g. `std::variant` or `std::any` as return type, but you can't change return type through any runtime mechanics.

Comment: Is there any way I could define it as a macro somehow?

Comment: @nevets: A macro is token-based text replacement prior to compilation, i.e. whatever comes out of the preprocessor gets fed to the compiler. And the compiler needs to know the return type **at compile time** (as it needs to reserve memory accordingly). No way around it.

Answer (score 0):

> parameter is not known until an object is constructed..

answer is
Yes if above meant in static way
No if above meant in dynamic way

No code given above meant no useful way

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, cannot comment on anything yet)

You are not able to have one function that has different types of returns (would not fit the technical definition of a function anymore), but if you are able to check the parameter that you say might be `== 1` or `> 1` you could probably make a call to one of two different methods, each performing your desired operation for their respective cases.